# webpack-dev-server extremely slow to load on new machine

Tags: webgl, webxr

I've been working on a project from my laptop for the past few months. When webpack compiles my code, reloading the page takes around 1 second.

I've now moved to my desktop, and loading the page takes about 11 seconds in Chrome. I'm using the same version of node, webpack-dev-server and webpack on both machines (windows 10).

Chrome:
[image]

Edge:
[image]

Blazing fast in Chrome on my other machine:
[image]

I've also disabled all the extensions to no avail. I can't find a pattern, but this is not consistent on edge, it would load for the same 11 seconds there as well, but not always. Any ideas how i could address this?

Comment: Are you running any virus scanners?

Comment: I don’t have anything other than the windows built in stuff

Comment: I think it has something to do with obtaining the webgl context, and might not be related to webpack

Comment: Looks like its related to this: 

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202090&q=context%20hanging&can=2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This wasn't related to webpack at all, it just looked weird. The issue seems to have something to do with steam (or steamVR), and there was a bug report for chrome:

https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1202090#c38

Opening two tabs, and reloading them side by side would not suffer from this 11 second delay. Updating steam seems to have resolved the issue.